# How to trigger an application to send data to my server?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'd like to get some information from the app installed from time to time, even if this one is in background.

Previously I did it sending a GCM message, without notification just a data-message but it seems not working anymore.

So I'd like to know how to ask the application to send data or anything else on the app side to periodically send data.

I saw the GCM Network Manager which could help me but Google doesn't talk about it anymore with FCM.

Another feature removed?

What are the possibilities?

Comment: Would you like to trigger the app from your server to send some information or it's OK if the app can send the information periodically without your server intervention?

Comment: @josemgu91 I would prefer to do it on the server initiative but as I said, it seems that data-message are no more received in background. I have a working project built with studio 1.5.2, FCM 9.2.0, java 1.7 which works perfectly but now I rebuild it with studio 2.1.2, sdk updated, java 1.8, but same app code, it doesn't work anymore. So strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Firebase Job Dispatcher](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android), it is the successor to GCM Network Manager.

Answer (score 0):

if you are the one who developed the application you have endless options, you can schedule your server to send GCM message to your app and your app on receive of that message it must build xml/json message with data you looking for and call a service from your server with that information.

Comment: unfortunately, I'm not sure. As I said it's what I did and if was effectively working again recently, but based on my tests these last days and on several posts about this problem, I wonder if FCM data-message behavior didn't change recently. And the Google doc is really fuzzy on the subject.

Comment: Did it stop working after switching from GCM to FCM?

Comment: no because my published app currently works with FCM 9.2.0  but this same project just rebuilt, but after studio, sdk, java updates doesn't work anymore. So unfortunately, I cannot say what caused the problem.